# How to set cell height in UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let height = self.navigationController?.navigationBar.frame.size.height
    return view.frame.size.height - height!
}
```

I want to change the cell size — I use only one cell.

My purpose is to fit the screen. However, in my case, the cell is scrolled.

I think it is necessary to calculate the safe area. What if I do not have a smaller or larger screen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please calculate like below for height, includes safe area code.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let height = view.bounds.height -  view.safeAreaInsets.top - view.safeAreaInsets.bottom
    return  height!
}
```

Comment: Good! That's what I wanted. Thank you